# WPF Expand a grid outside an expander

Tags: wpf

I have a status bar with an expander in it, and a grid with some content. How can I have the expander expand the grid, without nesting it in the status bar, and therefor effecting all other status bar items when its expanded?

```
    <StatusBar>    
       //Other status items
       <Expander ExpandDirection="Up" Header="Operations" />
       //Other status items
    </StatusBar>

    <Grid Name="the_grid" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      //Content
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Use a `Popup` control.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Its not a listed type in the toolbox.

Comment: A `Popup` will be displayed above the window, so it will not resize your grid. See [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFPopup.aspx) for a tutorial.

Comment: That does not move and stay in the window of the application properly.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want something simmilar to ComboBox funcionality. Look at ComboBox control template. Combobox uses a popup control to show items on top of other items and basicaly outside the combobox position.

You can edit Expander's control template and use similar approach there.

If you don't want to spend too much time with that, you can use small trick:

```
    <StatusBar>
        <StatusBarItem Content="Item 1" />
        <StatusBarItem Content="Item2" Margin="20,0" />

        <Menu BorderThickness="0">
            <MenuItem Header="Item 3 (expandable)" Foreground="{StaticResource Accent}" BorderThickness="0" Background="#333">
                <MenuItem Header="Item 3.1" BorderThickness="0" />
                <MenuItem Header="Item 3.2" BorderThickness="0" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu> 
    </StatusBar>
```